# Unexpected Token : when trying to parse a JSON string

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse this JSON string:

```
{ "RESULTS": [ { "name": "Thessaloniki GR", "type": "Sailing", "l": "/sailing-weather/beach:Porto%20Carras%20Marina 45904" }, { "name": "Thessaloniki, Greece", "type": "city", "c": "GR", "zmw": "00000.1.16622", "tz": "Europe/Athens", "tzs": "EET", "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.16622" } ] }
```

which is retrieved from [here](http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?&format=jsonp&query=Thessaloniki)

This is my snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#w11").autocomplete({
        source: function (a, b) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    format: "jsonp",
                    query: a.term
                },
                success: function (a) {
                    for (i in data.RESULTS) {
                        console.log(data.RESULTS);
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });


});​
```

Which gives me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` on the first line which is `{ "RESULTS": [`

How can I parse the JSON Results?

Comment: ur jquery code have errors

Comment: Your code has a few issues, but they're not the problem. The issues are 1. You have several missing semicolons. I strongly recommend **not** relying on the idiocy that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9). 2. You appear to be falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)* as you don't declare `i` anywhere. 3. Your loop is repeatedly logging your entire response via `console.log(data.RESULTS);`. You probably meant `console.log(data.RESULTS[i]);` or something.

Comment: AND the `a` in `success: function (a)` should be `data`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've told jQuery to expect [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), not [JSON](http://json.org):

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

...but the result is JSON. JSON-P and JSON are fundamentally different things. Here's an example JSON response:

```
{"foo": 42}
```

Here's what a JSON-P response might look like:

```
callback({"foo": 42});
```

or

```
callback({foo: 42});
```

If `http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/a` is not on the same origin as the document your code is running in, you won't be able to retrieve JSON from it via ajax because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (unless the server in question supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), allows your origin for the request, and the browser the user has also supports CORS). Which I suspect is why you tried to use JSON-P, which works cross-origin. The thing is, though, that the **server** has to support JSON-P as well. Despite the `format=jsonp` in the URL, the server is not responding with JSON-P, but with JSON.

In the comments, you linked to [their docs for that API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=autocomplete-api), which show that they *do* support JSON-P for it, just using a non-standard argument name in the URL (`cb` instead of the much more common `callback`).

So this should work (I've also fixed the issues with the code I mentioned in my comment on the question):

```
$.ajax({
    url:      "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp:    "cb",     // <================= New bit is here
    data:     {
        format: "json", // <=== "json" not "jsonp" according to the docs, but I think the "cb" argument overrides it anyway
        query:  a.term
    },
    success:  function (data) { // <=== `data`, not `a`
        var i;
        for (i in data.RESULTS) {
            console.log(data.RESULTS[i]); // <=== Use [i] here
        }
    }
}); // <=== Semicolon was missing
```

And in fact it does work: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/oqecik/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/oqecik/1/edit)

The `jsonp` argument tells jQuery what URL parameter to use to define the name of the JSON-P callback. The default is the standard `callback` but that API uses a non-standard argument.

Comment: I see. I initially used JSON but because of the Same Origin Policy I was confused and turned it to JSONP. Then if you cant retrieve JSON without the same origin, why do they provide it in the first place?
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=autocomplete-api

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Probably for retrieval server-side, for instance in PHP via [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). If you look at their [code examples page](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples), the vast majority of them are for server-side use. Note, though, that they **do** support JSON-P for some operations. Oh, wait, look -- they **do** support JSON-P for that op, you're just missing an argument. Updating answer...

Comment: Thanks a million. I have not only learned my mistakes, but you taught me alot

Comment: @jQuerybeast: No worries, I'm really glad that helped! :-)