# Wunderground Autocomplete API error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, api, get, cors, wunderground

I have created a GET request using axios in react as follows:

```
 searchCity: function(){
    return axios.get('https://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=lond' + '&format=JSON')
  }
```

However I am presented with the error:

```
https://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=lond&format=JSON. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Even though this is a public api and no access keys or anything are required.
Is there another way to get the JSON data from this url?

Comment: I've been looking into it and am thinking its the way wundergrounds api is setup. If I browse to that url in the browser I get data back and I made a jsfiddle running the same request and get the same error you are receiving. Strange thing is when looking at my request in fiddler as I make it in jsfiddle I can see it return a 200 and get data back but in the browser I am still getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I'm experiencing, not sure how to possible change the 'origin' value in the header of my request, not sure if that would work wither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I spent around an hour on this!
In the end it seems that certain servers do not carry the:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

in their response headers, however some server are compatible with JSONP rather than standard JSON requests. The thing is, though, that the server has to support JSON-P as well. Despite the format=jsonp in the URL, the server is not responding with JSON-P, but with JSON.

In this case it was and it was and the following code works using react-jsonp:

```
searchCity: function(){
    return jsonp('https://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=lond', { param: 'cb' }, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data.RESULTS);
    })
```

More information on this issue was found here:

[Unexpected Token : when trying to parse a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899767/unexpected-token-when-trying-to-parse-a-json-string)